# Chromium-based browsers look blurry

Tags: google-chrome

I've been interested in passing to Linux for a while, so I dual-booted it with Windows to test it out, been having fun so far.

There's a thing that has been bothering me though, I use a website very often, and it looks very blurry. I like accessing this website through Brave or Chrome, and well, those specifically look really blurry, to the point where I literally started using other browsers (Firefox in this case, which I don't like at all). To be able to have a good experience
I have been googling for probably 3, 4 hours in the past two days, trying to find a solution, and none has worked so far.

I have tried the "Disable Hardware Acceleration", changing something in the google-chrome.desktop, re-installed my GPU Drivers (Using NVIDIA GTX 1050TI, version of drivers 510 if I recall correctly).
I've tried quite a lot. But nothing has worked, so I decided to make this post to see if anything new pops up, or anyone with experience with it has something to offer.

(Screenshots look even worse in Imgur, to try picturing a better image for you, it's like comparing 1080p against 480p, the difference is huge comparing them. In the pictures uploaded to Imgur that is not clear, just wanted to say that.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghfIV.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find this article? https://www.askvg.com/fix-blurry-text-and-font-display-problems-in-google-chrome/

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906602/blurry-downscaled-images-in-chrome

Comment: @PonJar I hadn't seen the first, but I tried those that I could and none made a difference.
Second one, I didn't understand where to place that specifically, but I did see something similar that was used on the backend of the website (thing that of course I can't access)

Comment: I think it help you. It worked with my google chrome.
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/10/fix-firefox-blurry-wayland-fonts-ubuntu